# Serializing Doctrine's collection with custom key

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using JMSSerializer to serialize a Doctrine's entity collection into json.
As expected, the result is something like this:

```
    data: [
      {
        "id":1,
        "title":"Entity 1"
      },
      {
        "id":55,
        "title":"Entity 55"
      }
    ]
```

But I would like to specify the key of each object based on it's ID to have something like this instead:

```
    data: [
      1: {
        "id":1,
        "title":"Entity 1"
      },
      55: {
        "id":55,
        "title":"Entity 55"
      }
    ]
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you should take a look at [this](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers)

Comment: A simple (and encouraged) solution is to transform data yourself before handing it to Jms. $myMap = [$e1->getId()=>$e1,$e2->getId()=>$e2, ...,] then serialize $myMap

Comment: Yeah, already thought about it, but my object is more complex than my example, as I have three levels of nested objects.